# How can I upload a file to several servers at once? Can FileReader or hidden iframes do this? Is there another method?

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, filereader

Each server is connected to a network, but not the internet. Each server runs a web server and serves pages with PHP. The user attaches a laptop to the network and navigates to the home page of one of the servers. A web page pops up and then the user navigates to a form where they can upload a file from their laptop's hard drive to the servers they select on the network.

I got this to work by sending the files out one at a time with hidden iframes. But I had issues sending out the files asynchronously. Firefox works asynchronously by doing a deep copy of the input element in Javascript. Chrome works asynchronously by doing a shallow copy (just passing a reference) of the input element in Javascript. I'd rather not build code that works differently for Chrome and Firefox. Did I miss something with using hidden iframes asynchronously?

Now I'm starting to look at using FileReader and perhaps Web Workers with FileReader. The problem I'm running into is Base64 encoding issues. The readDataAsURL() function uses Base64 encoding. It makes the data larger, and takes time to decode. Right now, my main concern is the larger size. I'm sending a file which is a few GB in size, and the file is going to embedded servers. The server definitely does not have enough memory to hold the whole file in memory at once. It just barely has space for one copy of the final file on disk. I think this would work if I had enough room for both the larger Base64 encoded file and the final file on disk. But, the hardware is limited in my case. Would using readAsArrayBuffer() have the same limitations? Right now, I'm looking for a simple, complete example which sends the file with readAsArrayBuffer() and stores the file on disk with PHP.

Is there a way to upload files with hidden iframes and Web Workers? I don't see a way to get these to work together.

Am I missing a different method which would work?

Comment: You should post the actual code. What you wrote about Firefox and Chrome behavior really doesn't make sense.

Comment: i think better solution is to have a server script which accepts the file once, and makes sure the uploaded file is sent/synchronised to any other server, it will make your life and code much easier and maintainable

Comment: Thanks, Nikos M. That solution is definitely a possibility I have considered and discussed. I don't think I could kick something like that off from the JavaScript. Are you saying kick off the script from the PHP side after the file has already been uploaded to one device? Or setting it up a separate daemon? Either way, in my specific scenario, this might load one of the embedded servers too much and/or for too long to be acceptable to the end users. But definitely a possibility. Thanks again.

Comment: Passing large files via HTTP can start to consume resources very quickly. Shockwave Flash might be a better method. This can handle larger files much better.